# Pandas to_numpy() results in an array of lists. How do I get a 2D numpy array from this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column of lists, and each list contains the same number of values.

If I do

```
df['column'].to_numpy()
```

I get an array of lists:

```
array([list([0, 4688, 11, 43486, 40508, 13, 5,...
       list([0, 40928, 17707, 22705, 9, 38312, 2..
       list([0, 6766, 368, 3551, 28837,..
      dtype=object)
```

How do I get a 2D array instead?

Comment: That's odd. Can you share the content of your `df["column"]` ?

Comment: Show how to construct this dataframe. Does any list have a non-numeric element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
np.array(df['column'].tolist())
```

Or you can simply stack them:

```
np.stack(df['column'].to_numpy())
```

This will stack your lists on top of each other and output is a 2-D array. You have to make sure lists are of the same length. Numpy arrays are rectangular.

Comment: Technically true, but likely doesn't address the root of the problem

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure what you mean. It is one of many solutions. I added another one that deals with pandas first if that is what you mean by _root of the problem_ :D

Comment: Getting a dataframe with lists is usually weird

Comment: That being said, +1 for the cleanest solution based on the information provided

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree a better practice is to not include same length lists in a column, but I can see applications were having it sounds reasonable too. Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: It's late and I'm nit picking instead of getting rest :) like you say, something that is usually code smell isn't always actually wrong

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not too crazy, in my situation that led me to this answer, if the original data comes as a mixed list then pandas keeps the numerics as their own list, e.g. data_foo = [[[2*i, 2*i+1], chr(i+97)] for i in range(5)]; df = pd.DataFrame(data_foo, columns=['numeric', 'character'])

Answer (score 1):

You can use list `list comprehension`

```
>>> df
                 A
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> np.array([x for x in df['A']])
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=np.array(df['column']).reshape(2,2)
```

- It will convert your desire columns into array

*for 2d array you can use reshape function on numpy But you should have proper value in data to corvert eg (2,2) is used  if you have 4 numbers of data it indicate (row,columns)*

Comment: This actually should return 1-D array of lists again. OP wants a 2-D array.

Comment: The shape is not necessarily `(2,2)` either. The example in the question shows you that it is actually not of shape `(2,2)`. You might have been confusing shape with dimensions.